# Import QWebEngineView into PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, qt, pyqt5

I'm working on a project that should interact with Google Maps API.
Usually I use `QWebView` as a widget to load web pages. But my simple html page is not loading there. However if I load the original google maps page, everything works fine but slowly though.

Checked some advices, there are recommendations to use `QWebEngineView` instead of `QWebView`. But `QWebEngineView` cannot be imported before QGIS application is started.

I thought there should be a workaround like here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/26048#issuecomment-495884206

I thought putting

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
```

into `startup.py` would do the thing, but not.
So any other ways to get a better work with HTML pages?